# The script is working just after one refresh on angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I tried to implement a tree view similar with this( https://iamrohit.in/javascript-css-horizontal-employee-treeview/ ) but the script only work just after first refresh of the page, I'm using angular, is there an option to load the page before so the user doesn't need to refresh the page every time because that's not my intention on this project.

Comment: How are you redirecting to the page? Using ```href``` or ```routerOutlet```?

Comment: i'm using routerOutlet

Comment: ```navigateToMenuPath(path:string): void {
    this.router.navigate([path]);
  }```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to move your script in your typescript component file like this

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    $(function () {
      $('.genealogy-tree ul').hide();
      $('.genealogy-tree>ul').show();
      $('.genealogy-tree ul.active').show();
      $('.genealogy-tree li').on('click', function (e) {
          
          var children = $(this).find('> ul');
            if (children.is(":visible")) children.hide('fast').removeClass('active');
            else children.show('fast').addClass('active');
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    });
  }
```